# Filter a dataframe through for-loop and then storing into new dataframe

Tags: r

I have a df for the script of a TV show with two columns, one for the speaker and one for the line they are speaking. I would like to filter all the lines by the speaker, and then count the words of all their lines and then store that information into a new df like this:

```
Speaker Words
John    10000
Bob     20000
Doe     30000
```

Sample from df:

```
line                                                                    speaker
All right Jim. Your quarterlies look very good.                         Michael
```

So far I have come up with this:

```
df1 <- lines %>%
  filter(speaker == 'John')

wordcount(df1$line)
```

I was wondering if there's a for-loop method or other alternatives that would make this process easier? Thanks!

Comment: please provide your sample data using `dput`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear as to why you are after a for loop. There are a few approaches that you can take here. BTW, you should always indicate the packages that you are using in your example.

First, lets create a reproducible example. We will call the `wordcount` function, from the ngram namespace without adding the package.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Speaker = rep(c("John", "Bob", "Doe"),2),
                   Words = NA)
  df[df$Speaker == "John",]$Words <- "All right Jim. Your quarterlies look very good"
  df[df$Speaker == "Bob",]$Words <- "You all look good, except for John"
  df[df$Speaker == "Doe",]$Words <- "John, your performance is terrible"
```

First, we can just return aggregated sums using `tapply` and coerce into a data.frame on the fly.

```
data.frame(Speaker = sort(unique(df$Speaker)), 
           total_words = as.numeric(tapply(df$Words, 
           df$Speaker, ngram::wordcount)) )
```

Using the pipe approach we can follow your example and return total words for a single speaker

```
df %>% 
  filter(Speaker == "John") %>%
  summarize(total_words = ngram::wordcount(Words)) %>%
  as.numeric()
```

Or, using a pipe approach, total words for all Speakers as a data.frame

```
df %>%
  group_by(Speaker) %>%
  summarize(total_words = ngram::wordcount(Words)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! So you added in the individual lines for each speaker, is there a way to select ALL the lines by that speaker?